# The address of C ++ pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, x86-64, memory-address

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    unsigned int a =5;
    unsigned int *pint = NULL;

    cout << "&a = " << &a << endl;
    cout << " &pint = " << &pint << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
&a = 0x6ffe04
&pint = 0x6ffdf8
```

I'm wondering why the address of `pint` equals `0x6ffdf8`. `pint` is an `unsigned int` (4 bytes), shouldn't the address of it be `0x6ffe00`?

Comment: There is no requirement that variables declared sequentially will be stored sequentially in memory.   In other words, the compiler is not required to ensure any particular relationship between `&a` and `&pint` in your code - they could be stored in reverse order, there could be a gigabyte of memory between them.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for your reply! Your answer is very clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `pint` is not an unsigned int. It is a pointer to an unsigned int.
Pointer can have a different size and can especially have the size 8.
It could hence fit into 0x6ffdfc before 0x6ffe04.
But it also has bigger alignment needs, it wants an address dividable by 8, so `0x...c` is out, it needs e.g. `0x...8`.

With 463035818_is_not_a_number I agree that this not really predictable, there are implementation specific aspects. That is why I phrase "softly" with  "can", "wants", "e.g."....

Comment: perpahs worth mentioning that you are talking about implementation specifics. In principle the adresses could be anything

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I incorporated your contribution. Thanks.

Comment: Even if `pint` were an `unsigned int`, whether it is 4 bytes or not is also implementation-defined. ;-)